# Doctrine entity proxy exception

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a big problem with one of my entities in my Symfony project.

Some code first:
Address entity

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
class Address
{
/**
* @var integer
*/
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $street;

/**
 * @var string|null
 */
private $postalCode;

/**
 * @var string|null
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string|null
 */
private $province;

/**
 * @var float
 */
private $latitude;

/**
 * @var float
 */
private $longtitude;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set street
 *
 * @param string $street
 * @return Address
 */
public function setStreet($street)
{
    $this->street = $street;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get street
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getStreet()
{
    return $this->street;
}

/**
 * Set postalCode
 *
 * @param integer $postalCode
 * @return Address
 */
public function setPostalCode($postalCode)
{
    $this->postalCode = $postalCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get postalCode
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getPostalCode()
{
    return $this->postalCode;
}

/**
 * Set city
 *
 * @param string $city
 * @return Address
 */
public function setCity($city)
{
    $this->city = $city;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get city
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->city;
}

/**
 * Set province
 *
 * @param string $province
 * @return Address
 */
public function setProvince($province)
{
    $this->province = $province;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get province
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProvince()
{
    return $this->province;
}

/**
 * Set latitude
 *
 * @param string $latitude
 * @return Address
 */
public function setLatitude($latitude)
{
    $this->latitude = $latitude;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get latitude
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLatitude()
{
    return $this->latitude;
}

/**
 * Set longtitude
 *
 * @param string $longtitude
 * @return Address
 */
public function setLongtitude($longtitude)
{
    $this->longtitude = $longtitude;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get longtitude
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLongtitude()
{
    return $this->longtitude;
}
}
```

Address entity mapping:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Address:
type: entity
table: addresses

id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    street:
        type: string
        nullable: false
    postalCode:
        name: postal_code
        type: string
        nullable: true
    city:
        type: string
        nullable: false
    province:
        type: string
        nullable: true
    latitude:
        type: decimal
        scale: 12
        precision: 18
        nullable: true
    longtitude:
        type: decimal
        scale: 12
        precision: 18
        nullable: true
```

Venue entity mapping:
AppBundle\Entity\Venue (shortened for the sake of example):

```
type: entity
table: venues
manyToOne:
    address:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Address
        joinColumn:
            name: address_id
            referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: false
        cascade: ["persist"]
```

The problem is that I face an exception being thrown:

> Notice: Array to string conversion 500 Internal Server Error -
>   ContextErrorException
>   here `$proxyCode = strtr($this->proxyClassTemplate, $venueholders);` (in vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php at line 280).

When I remove the relation, everything works correctly so it tells me there's some kind of issue with Address entity.

I've tried to clear the cache - no luck. Mapping looks ok to me, getters/setters are correct.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to reinstall your vendors completely? I see one issue in your question: `$proxyCode = strtr($this->proxyClassTemplate, $venueholders);`.

Line 280 of ProxyGenerator class should look like this: [`https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php#L280`](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php#L280).

Did you try to apply search & replace on your code by any chance?

Comment: Yes! Got it! I replaced "place" with "venue", but I completely forgot about it and I was sure I applied the change to the `src` directory only! Thanks for both of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try `column:` instead of `name:`

```
postalCode:
        column: postal_code
        type: string
        nullable: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still the same exception unfortunately :(

Comment: @user1854344 Are you spacing the elements correctly?

Comment: Yes, I've already triple checked it. Also, checked entities getters/setters.

Comment: @user1854344 try substituing AppBundle\Entity\Address by Addres

Comment: I've already tried this. Same as FQDN. Tried that once again, no luck. I have no idea.

Comment: `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info` does not return any error or exception. All mappings are correct.

Comment: I guess you'll have tried it but just in case: if you're in dev environment, run php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env dev . Could you also post the code of the venues entity?

Comment: Yes, of course. `Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.` I'm hopeless :( Thanks for your time, I've posted this question in few places, you are the only one to respond and try to help. I appreciate this.

It's been 7 hours for me this this issue now :( Wehn I delete database, it's being created correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68997/discussion-between-acontell-and-user1854344).